# C++ lambda assignable to bool

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying `for_each`, and realized that a `lambda` is assignable to `bool`.

```
    #include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<algorithm>

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
        auto l = [](int i) -> void
        {
           std::cout<<i<<'\n';
        };
        std::cout << "the sum is " <<std::boolalpha<<std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),  l ) << "\n";

        bool b = l;
        std::cout<<b<<'\n';

    }
```

We know that a lambda without any capture can be treated like a `C function`. But not very sure about boolean conversion.

Once we reference capture, boolean conversion stops.

```
    auto l = [&](int i) -> void
    {
       std::cout<<a<<i<<'\n';
       a+=i;
    };
    bool b = l; //Does not compile.
```

So, what is the reason for boolean conversion??

Comment: "can be treated like a C function". Function, pointer-to-function, bool.

Comment: Which compiler are you on? VS2015 says: `cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_ee0d2f1d2fe76619730d5bf271cc6631>' to 'bool'`

Comment: g++ (GCC) 5.2.0 -- coliru